# If $f(x)$ is continuous, then $f(x+t)$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This might be an obvious question, but I couldn't prove it rigorously.

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous at every $a$. Then, for every a for every $e>0$, there exists $d>0$ such that $(|x-a|<d \Rightarrow \left|f(x)-f(a)\right|<e).$

Let $g(x)=g(x+t)$. 
I want to show that for every $a$ for every $e>0$, there exists $d>0$ such that $(|x-a|<d \Rightarrow \left|g(x)-g(a)\right|<e).$

\begin{align*}
|g(x)-g(a)| &=|f(x+t)-f(a+t)|\\
&=|f(x+t)-f(x)+f(x)-f(a+t)| \\
& \leq |f(x+t)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(a+t)|\\
&=|f(x+t)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(a)+f(a)-f(a+t)| \\
& \leq |f(x+t)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)-f(a+t)|.
\end{align*}

But I dont know how to go further. I've spent so much time on this simple problem, but still cant figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use the fact that the function $x \to x + t$ is continuous.

Comment: what @anomaly said coupled with the fact that continuity is preserved under composition of continuous functions

Comment: Oh I see, it was so easy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint $|x-a|=|(x+t)-(a+t)|$ so apply continuity in points $X=x+t$ and $A=a+t$ then $|f(X)-f(A)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Wow, yes, thanks!

Comment: Did you mean "Let $g(x)=\mathbf f(x+t)$"?